# Rubyvis: subscripts/superscripts

Tags: ruby, plot, protovis

I am considering using [Rubyvis](http://rubyvis.rubyforge.org/), a Ruby Port of the Protovis library, to generate plots for scientific publications. Rubyvis renders charts as SVG files. However, I haven't found a way to use subscripts or superscripts in text (such as diagram titles or axis labels).

[The documentation for the Label class](http://rubyvis.rubyforge.org/rubyvis/Rubyvis/Label.html) states:

> The character data must be plain text (unicode), though the text can be styled
>   using the *font* property. If rich text is needed, external HTML elements can be
>   overlaid on the canvas by hand.

This sounds like the library itself does not support this functionality.

Is there a way to get subscripts and superscripts (and possible other rich text) directly in the output graphics file, when is is not embedded in a website?